# Is it possible to query for VIP (with endpoint ports) both in emulated compute environment and in cloud "cleanly"?

Tags: azure, f#, azure-web-roles, azure-compute-emulator

I have two Web Roles, another of which provides a data API an another one hosts a frontend www site and then some compute roles that produce data.

What I would like to achieve is in the www Web Role to query the VIP of the data API Web Role by running a query function that abstracts the details if I'm running locally or in Azure. It looks like querying the `PublicIPEndpoint` would work in Azure, but not locally. The need would be such that I could further give out, say, some URL constants for JavaScript.

Is there a better way than to hardcode some string or, say, read the `.csdef` file with a relative path and take it from there?

In code crudely something like

```
let IsInAzureFabric =
    try
        RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable       
    with _ ->
        false                

let IsInAzureCloud =
    try
        IsInAzureFabric && not RoleEnvironment.IsEmulated
    with _ ->
        false

let GetVirtualIP(roleName, endPoint) =        
    try
        if IsInAzureCloud then
            //Collect the protocol (http/https) from the endpoint information and pick only one endpoint as it's the one shown on the loadbalancer...
            RoleEnvironment.Roles.[roleName].Instances
            |> Seq.map(fun roleInstance -> "http://" + roleInstance.InstanceEndpoints.[endPoint].PublicIPEndpoint.ToString())
        elif IsInAzureFabric then
            //In local development fabric...
            Seq.ofList ["http://localhost:8080"]
        else
            //This is locally outside of Azure Fabric (or in virtual machine?).
            Seq.ofList ["http://localhost:1943"]
    with _ ->
        Seq.empty
```